# Custom List missing sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff630940.aspx#odc_sp14_qn_CreateListwithNewContentType_CreatetheList)  but when I get to step 4("Select Custom List.") I don't have this list.

I only have one list and that is "import spread sheet".

How do I install missing lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement and deploy the custom **New Announcements** content type yourself.

It's not available out-of-the-box:

> Note: This Quick Note assumes that you
>   already created a new content type
>   named **New Announcements** with two
>   fields named **Team Project** and **Company**.
>   To learn how to create a content type,
>   see [Create Custom Content Types in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff630942.aspx).